# Can I get a CGColor from CGGradient?

Tags: ios, core-graphics, drawrect, cgpath, cgcolor

I need to get a `CGColor` from a `CGGradientRef`, and use the color as a stroke colour in a drawing app for iOS 7. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw the gradient to an image context, get the pixel buffer for the image, then create a color from that pixel (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22174368/ios-cant-get-correct-pixel-color-of-cgimageref/)).

Otherwise, `CGGradientRef` is an opaque type, and there isn't any way to get information out of it. For my own apps, I've also created a wrapper object around `CGGradientRef` that creates the gradient and stores the colors / locations it was created with.